# existing 2 wires to new 3 wire + ground switch

Tags: wiring

My existing switch has one black and one white wire. My new switch has a black (live) wire , a red (load) wire and a white (neutral) wire. Also a ground wire. I have tried just using the black /black and white/white connections but it does not work. I have also added the red to the black/black and this does not work either. How do I wire this new switch.

Comment: You run new cable, or you don't use this switch. You appear to have a perfectly normal, legal prior to the 2011 NEC and still legal as a grandfathered item switch loop. You don't have a neutral. Your new switch needs one (thus, the 2011 code change.)

Comment: It's hard to get in too much trouble with a **switch**, but just the same -- never "experiement" / "try things".  This isn't an Arduino.  Some combinations will work as desired... *and then, they will kill  you*.

Comment: What make/model is your new switch?

Answer (score 3):

#### TL;DR You can't, at least not easily.

Your old setup is a **switch loop**. That means you have, essentially:

- Power from the breaker black hot/white neutral to the box at the light
- White hot goes down to the switch and comes back on black switched hot (because cables are black/white, so we get to *not* have white == neutral like it does in most other places)
- Black switched hot connects to the light along with white neutral from the breaker.

Or a short version: breaker -> light -> switch

If you had the logical: breaker -> switch -> light

then you would have neutral passing through the box (2 whites wire nutted together). But builders often used switch loops to save a few feet of wire.

Your new switch requires neutral. It uses a common convention of:

- Black hot
- Red switched hot
- White neutral

New code requires neutral in most switch boxes for exactly this reason. But your house (and mine) predates that rule. With "dumb" switches that doesn't matter, but for many timers, dimmers, smart switches, WiFi switches, etc. neutral is needed.

Your choices are:

- Run a new cable (not just one extra wire) with hot/switched-hot/neutral/ground to the switch box.
- Find a switch that does *not* need neutral. For some things this will be easy. Unfortunately, for some things it will be a bit harder as the old method of getting power for a switch without using neutral was to leak current through the lights when "off". That often causes problems with LED lighting - flickering, dim glow, etc.